# AMD switches texture and normal VBOs around

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl, vbo

AMD switches the locations of my texture VBO and my normals VBO. This leads to some odd results, if I run the NVIDIA code on AMD and vice versa.

*To specify; this is from results on GTX660 and A6 APU (I'm assuming the result would be the same for any NVIDIA or AMD card)

The code in question:

**Full source code**
 https://github.com/DigitalQR/QRDare

**Relevent parts**

Main Class:

```
public class TestingMain {


public static void main(String[] args){
    QRWindow window = new QRWindow("Test", 640, 480);


    Shader shader = new Shader(new File("Test/shader.vs"), new File("Test/shader.fs"));
    shader.bindFragData("out_colour");
    shader.genAttribList(new int[]{Loader.LOC_POSITION, Loader.LOC_TEXTURECOORD, Loader.LOC_NORMAL}, new String[]{"in_location", "in_textureCoord", "in_normal"});
    shader.genUniformList(new String[]{"cam_location", "cam_rotation","light_location"});


    RawModel model = Loader.loadRawModel(
            new float[]{//Vertex
                    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
                    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
            }, 
            new float[]{//Tex
                    0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
                    0f, 1f, 1f, 1f
            }, 
            new float[]{//Norm
                    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
                    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f
            }, 
            new int[]{//Elem
                    0,1,2, 1,3,2
            },
            Loader.loadTexture("Test/Metal", GL11.GL_LINEAR)
            );

    RawModel model2 = Loader.loadRawModel(
            new float[]{//Vertex
                    0, 1, 1, 1,
                    0, 0, 1, 0,
            }, 
            new float[]{//Tex
                    0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
                    0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f
            }, 
            new float[]{//Norm
                    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
                    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
            }, 
            new int[]{//Elem
                    0,1,2, 1,3,2
            },
            Loader.loadTexture("Test/Grass", GL11.GL_NEAREST)
            );
    Camera.setDepth(0.5f);

    while(!window.closeRequested()){
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)){
            Camera.getLocation().y+=0.1f;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)){
            Camera.getLocation().y-=0.1f;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)){
            Camera.getLocation().x-=0.1f;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)){
            Camera.getLocation().x+=0.1f;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_Q)){
            Camera.setRotation(Camera.getRotation()-0.1f);
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_E)){
            Camera.setRotation(Camera.getRotation()+0.1f);
        }

        shader.loadVector(shader.getUniformLocation("cam_location"), Camera.getLocation());
        shader.loadVector(shader.getUniformLocation("light_location"), Camera.getLocation());
        Camera.loadRotation(shader, shader.getUniformLocation("cam_rotation"));

        Renderer.render(model);
        Renderer.render(model2);


        window.update();
    }
    Loader.cleanUp();
    shader.destroy();
    window.close();
}
}
```

VBO Loader:

```
public class Loader {

public final static int LOC_POSITION = 0;
public final static int LOC_TEXTURECOORD = 1;
public final static int LOC_NORMAL = 2;

private static List<Integer> vaos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static List<Integer> vbos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static List<Integer> textures = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static RawModel loadRawModel(float[] positions, float[] textureCoords, float[] normals, int[] indices, int texture){
    int VAO = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    vaos.add(VAO);

    bindElements(indices);
    bindAttrib(LOC_POSITION, 2, positions);
    bindAttrib(LOC_TEXTURECOORD, 2, textureCoords);
    bindAttrib(LOC_NORMAL, 2, normals);

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    return new RawModel(VAO, indices.length, texture);
}

public static void bindAttrib(int location, int size, float[] data){
    int VBO = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    vbos.add(VBO);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
    buffer.put(data);
    buffer.flip();

    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(location, size, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}

public static void bindElements(int[] indices){
    int VBO = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    vbos.add(VBO);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indices.length);
    buffer.put(indices);
    buffer.flip();

    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

}

public static void cleanUp(){
    for(int vao:vaos){
        GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vao);
    }
    for(int vbo:vbos){
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vbo);
    }
    for(int texture:textures){
        GL11.glDeleteTextures(texture);
    }
}

public static int loadTexture(String fileName, int type){
    Texture texture = null;

    try {
        texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(fileName + ".png"), type);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int textureID = texture.getTextureID();
    textures.add(textureID);
    return textureID;
}
}
```

Renderer:

```
public class Renderer {

public static void render(RawModel model){
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVAO());

    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(Loader.LOC_POSITION);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(Loader.LOC_TEXTURECOORD);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(Loader.LOC_NORMAL);

    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, model.getTexture());

    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);


    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(Loader.LOC_NORMAL);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(Loader.LOC_TEXTURECOORD);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(Loader.LOC_POSITION);

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}

public static void render(Entity entity){
    render(entity.getModel());
}
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 in_location;
in vec2 in_textureCoord;
in vec2 in_normal;

uniform vec2 cam_location;
uniform mat4 cam_rotation;
uniform vec2 light_location;

out vec2 colour;
out vec2 normal;
out vec2 toLight;
out vec2 textureCoord;

void main(){
    textureCoord = in_textureCoord;
    colour = in_textureCoord;
    normal = normalize(in_normal);
    toLight = normalize(light_location-in_location);

    gl_Position = (vec4(in_location-cam_location, 1.0, 1.0)*cam_rotation).xyzw;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 colour;
in vec2 normal;
in vec2 toLight;
in vec2 textureCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture;

out vec4 out_colour;

void main(){

    float nDotl = dot(normal, toLight);
    float brightness = max(min(nDotl, 0.6), 0.1);

    out_colour = texture2D(texture, textureCoord.xy)*brightness;
    //out_colour = vec4(colour+0.5, 0.0, 1.0)*brightness;
}
```

Comment: AMD's GLSL compiler probably assigns vertex attributes locations in alphabetical order. `normal` comes before `textureCoord` in alphabetical order. It's possible that NV's compiler assigns attributes in the order they appear in the shader. In any case, you need to bind the attribute locations before linking, or the GLSL compiler will pick some arbitrary order for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [to the documentation](http://docs.gl/gl4/glBindAttribLocation)

> Attribute bindings do not go into effect until `glLinkProgram` is called

You seem to link only once and that appears to be before you call `genAttribList` which is the function that calls `glBindAttribLocation`. So, use `glLinkProgram` again at the end of `genAttribList` would be my suggestion.

Comment: This is not it works. glLinkProgram just makes the attribute bindings valid to use later on.

Comment: @datenwolf did I say something to the contrary?

Comment: You suggested to call glLinkProgram after genAttribList, while in fact it must be called before *and not* after.

Comment: @datenwolf are you sure? Neither the documentation nor my personal experience support your assertion.

Comment: Works perfectly fine after moving glLinkProgram the end of genAttribList; thanks

Comment: @PeterT: Both of you actually have me confused. I took a look at the github and I think there should only be one call to `glLinkProgram (...)` (your answer suggests you need to link twice), but it should come after or at the end (as Sam Potter mentions) of the method: `genAttribList` in `QRDare/src/core/visual/engine/shaders/Shader.java`. _To be honest, that method name does not make a lot of sense to me. It's doing a heck of a lot more than generating a list of attributes, it's linking and validating the GLSL program as well -- I'd consider splitting it into multiple methods._

Comment: @SamPotter: Similarly, the method `genUniformList` has to be called ***after*** your program is linked. To keep things consistent, I would make an entirely separate method that links and validates. Because there is just as much reason to call `glLinkProgram (...)` at the beginning of `genUniformList` as there is to call it at the end of `genAttribList`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I looked at this: https://github.com/DigitalQR/QRDare/blob/b51b62551b0a773a4d6df0aa63eb6117dc250613/src/core/visual/engine/shaders/Shader.java#L58-L63 revision (he changed it to what you are seeing an hour ago). I assumed that he wanted the `Shader` to be "completely constructed" after the constructor, so I thought he was not willing to remove the `glLinkProgram` there. The only option I saw was for it to be called again. I do realize that this OO wrapping of OpenGL constructs doesn't always make sense, but I didn't want to bash on OO again :P